# Laptop contrast function keys

Tags: keyboard-shortcuts, contrast

On my glossy narrow viewing angle LCD laptop, in addition to brightness, I would like to be able to adjust the contrast by pressing a function key.

At the console command prompt:

```
 ~ $ xgamma
```

returns:

```
 Red  0.900, Green  0.900, Blue  0.900
```

I would like to construct a command line that takes the last returned field of 0.900 multiply it by 1.1 (to get 0.990) and use that result as input value  to:

```
~ $  xgamma -gamma 0.990
```

A command line along the lines of:

```
~$ xgamma | last / 1.1 | xgamma -gamma
```

Then using my keyboard layout as an example, and using the distro dependent: Control Center > Keyboard Shortcuts, we can define a more contrast <kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>F5</kbd> function key above the existing brightness function key <kbd>Fn</kbd><kbd>F5</kbd>. For less contrast multiply by 1.1

Answer (score 0):

The FORTRAN solution.

From the Linux home directory make a subdirectory `/mygamma/`

The mygamma directory contains six files:
2 fortran program scripts: `contrastdown.f90` and `contrastup.f90`,
their executables `gammadown` and `gammaup`,
and a shebang file `xgammasave`
that saves the current xgamma value to a text file `xgammaval.txt`

The xgammasave file looks like this:

```
#!/bin/bash

xgamma |& tee ~/mygamma/xgammaval.txt
```

The `contrastup.f90` file looks like this:

```
program contrastup

 character(len=20):: string,string2,string3 ! variable type declarations

 real(kind(1.0)) :: x

 call system('/home/my_name/mygamma/xgammasave') ! write the xgamma value to a file

 open(unit=2,file='/home/my_name/mygamma/xgammaval.txt',action='read',status='old')

 read(unit=2,fmt=*)string,string2,string3 ! read the file

 read(string3,*)x            ! make a real from a string

 x=x/1.2                     ! change the contrast

  if (x .le. 0.1) goto 10    ! xgamma value can not be less than 0.1

 write(string,*)x            ! make a string from a real

 string2='xgamma -gamma ' // trim(string) ! concatenate 2 strings

 call system(string2)        ! pass the string to the command line

10 close(unit=2)

end program contrastup
```

and `contrastdown.f90`

```
program contrastdown

 character(len=20):: string,string2,string3 ! variable type declarations

 real(kind(1.0)) :: x

 call system('/home/my_name/mygamma/xgammasave')  ! write xgamma value to a file

 open(unit=2,file='/home/my_name/mygamma/xgammaval.txt',action='read',status='old')

 read(unit=2,fmt=*)string,string2,string3 ! read the record

 read(string3,*)x             ! make a real from a string

 x=x*1.2                      ! change the contrast

  if (x .ge. 10.0) goto 10   ! xgamma value can not be greater than 10.0

 write(string,*)x             ! make a string from a real

 string2='xgamma -gamma ' // trim(string) ! concatenate two strings

 call system(string2)         ! pass the string to the command line

10 close(unit=2)

end program contrastdown
```

Make the Fortran executable files `gammaup` and `gammadown`:

```
~/mygamma $ gfortran contrastup.f90 -o gammaup  

~/mygamma $ gfortran contrastdown.f90 -o gammadown
```

Depending on Linux flavor, from Control Center > Keyboard Shortcuts, under 'Custom Shortcuts', select 'add', in the name field enter the shortcut key name 'raise gamma' and in the command box enter `/home/my_name/mygamma/gammaup`
and likewise for the 'lower contrast' key with command `/home/my_name/mygamma/gammadown`

On my laptop <kbd>Fn</kbd><kbd>F6</kbd> and  <kbd>Fn</kbd><kbd>F5</kbd> are the default brightness up/down keys,
now above them the newly defined <kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>F6</kbd> and <kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>F5</kbd> are the contrast up/down keys. Vintage black and white movies now look nice on the glossy screen   :)

Can the FORTRAN solution be simplified by using a different, more appropriate language.